# How to return Left item from Validated?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a method that returns the following:

```
def myMethod(): Validated[List[MyError], MyClass] {
 ...
}
```

I have another method that expects `List[MyError]`

```
def otherMethod(errors: List[MyError]) { 
  ...
}
```

How can I call `otherMethod` with `List[MyError]` being returned from `myMethod`. Like below:

```
otherMethod(myMethod())
```

The above doesn't work and gives compilation error:

```
expected: List[MyError], actual: Validated[List[MyError], MyClass]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible outcomes of `myMethod` execution: it *either* . returns a list of errors or (presumably) a result of type `MyClass`. 
You are only talking about handling one of these outcomes. That is wrong. You should always keep both in mind, and handle them together. For example:

```
   myMethod() match {
     case Left(errors) => otherMethod(errors)
     case Right(result) => yetAnotherMethod(result)
   }
```